# Apache Isis: How to implement your custom submit form or page properly?

Tags: wicket, isis

I'm new at Apache Isis and I'm stuck.

I want to create my own submit form with editable parameters for search some entities and a grid with search results below.

Firstly, I created @DomainObject(nature=Nature.VIEW_MODEL) with search results collection, parameters for search and @Action for search.
After deeper research, I found out strict implementations for actions (For exapmle ActionParametersFormPanel). Can I use @Action and edit @DomainObject properties(my search parameters for action) without prompts?
Can I implement it by layout.xml?

Then I tried to change a component as described here: [6.2 Replacing page elements](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugvw/ugvw.html#_ugvw_extending_replacing-page-elements), but I was confused which ComponentType and IModel should I use, maybe ComponentType.PARAMETERS and ActionModel or implement my own IModel for my case.

Should I implement my own Wicket page for search and register it by PageClassList interface, as described here: [6.3 Custom pages](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugvw/ugvw.html#_ugvw_extending_custom-pages)
As I understood I need to replace page class for one of PageType, but which one should I change?

So, the question is how to implement such issues properly? Which way should I choose?

Thank you!

===================== UPDATE ===================

I've implemented HomePageViewModel in this way:

```
@DomainObject(
        nature = Nature.VIEW_MODEL,
        objectType = "homepage.HomePageViewModel"
)
@Setter @Getter
public class HomePageViewModel {

    private String id;
    private String type;

    public TranslatableString title() {
        return TranslatableString.tr("My custom search");
    }

    public List<SimpleObject> getObjects() {
        return simpleObjectRepository.listAll();
    }

    @Action
    public HomePageViewModel search(
            @ParameterLayout(named = "Id")
            String id,
            @ParameterLayout(named = "Type")
            String type
    ){
        setId(id);
        setType(type);
        // finding objects by entered parameters is not implemented yet
        return this;
    }

    @javax.inject.Inject
    SimpleObjectRepository simpleObjectRepository;
}
```

And it works in this way:
[image: Custom search reality]

I want to implement a built-in-ViewModel action with parameters without any dialog windows, smth like this:
[image: Custom search expectation]

1) Is it possible to create smth like ActionParametersFormPanel based on ComponentType.PARAMETERS and ActionModel and use this component as @Action in my ViewModel?

2) Or I should use, as you said, ComponentType.COLLECTION_CONTENTS? As I inderstand my search result grid and my search input panel will be like ONE my stub component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-1031) in our JIRA to implement a filterable/searchable component, but it hasn't yet made it to the top of the list for implementation.

As an alternative, you could have a view model that provides the parameters you want to filter on as properties, with a table underneath.  (I see you asked another question here on SO re properties on view models, so perhaps you are moving in that direction also... I've answered that question).

If you do want to have a stab at implementing that ticket, then the ComponentTYpe to use is COLLECTION_CONTENTS.  If you take a look at the isisaddons, eg for [excel](https://github.com/isisaddons/isis-wicket-excel/blob/master/cpt/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/wicket/excel/cpt/ui/CollectionContentsAsExcelFactory.java) or [gmap3](https://github.com/isisaddons/isis-wicket-gmap3/blob/master/cpt/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/wicket/gmap3/cpt/ui/CollectionOfEntitiesAsLocatablesFactory.java) then it might help get you started.

======= UPDATE TO ANSWER (based on update made to query) ==========

I have some good news for you.  v1.15.0-SNAPSHOT, which should be released in the couple of weeks, has support for "inline prompts".  You should find these give a user experience very similar to what you are after, with no further work needed on your part.

To try it out, check out the current trunk, and then load the simpleapp (in examples/application/simpleapp).  You should see that editing properties and invoking actions uses the new inline prompt style.

HTH
Dan

Comment: Thank you! Could you see the updated post, please? I have a few additional questions there.

Comment: I've checked out the current trunk 1.15-SNAPSHOT and run simpleapp. Actually this new functionality (inline prompts) doesn't quite fit in my case, but anyway inline prompts don't work in ViewModels (both for properties and actions), maybe the reason is the same why Editing.EDITABLE doesn't work in ViewModels.